# Convert date to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, datetime, date

I have a date in the following format in UI..

```
Eg: Thu. 03/01
```

I convert them to XMLGregorianCalendar as below explained.

```
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E. M/d");
final String dateStr = closeDate;
final Date dDate = format.parse(dateStr);

GregorianCalendar gregory = new GregorianCalendar();
gregory.setTime(dDate);

XMLGregorianCalendar dealCloseDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregory);
```

My Output is "3/06/70 05:00 AM" instead of "3/06/2011 05:00 AM". What is the chnage required to get the proper year.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels...I apologise for that. I didnt get any reply so i thought my Q was not understandable and i had to delete them. Once again sorry.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You didn't mention anything about how the year is supposed to be represented in this date conversion, but here is some pseudocode to get you started. Note that I don't explicitly deal with the timezone in this example:

```
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E. M/d");
final String dateStr = "Thu. 03/01";
final Date date = format.parse(dateStr);

GregorianCalendar gregory = new GregorianCalendar();
gregory.setTime(date);

XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
        .newXMLGregorianCalendar(
            gregory);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following code to achieve the same. May be a lengthy code but is working fine.

```
def gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar()
    def xmlGregorianCalendar = newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar)

    if (//past date is needed) {
        def date = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().time
        def cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.setTime(date)
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,-3); //subtract 3 days
        date.setTime(cal.getTime().getTime())
        gregorianCalendar.setTime(date)
        xmlGregorianCalendar =  newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar)
    }
```