# Issue formatting XMLGregorianCalendar - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

I am trying to format `XMLGregorianCalendar` using `SimpleDateFormat`. It works for `"yyyy-MM-dd"` but does not work for `"MM-dd-yyyy"`. What should I do to format it in `"MM-dd-yyyy"`

This one works :

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar convertToXMLGregorianCalendar(Date date)  {
    DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But this one throws `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar convertToXMLGregorianCalendar(Date date)  {
    DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    try {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 08-05-2021
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parseYear(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2910)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2801)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(DatatypeFactoryImpl.java:537)
    at com.usbank.mmc.transformation.pain002.utils.DateUtils.convertToXMLGregorianCalendar(DateUtils.java:16)
    at com.usbank.mmc.transformation.pain002.utils.DateUtils.main(DateUtils.java:24)
    ... 5 more
```

My Complete program

```
public final class DateUtils {

    public static XMLGregorianCalendar convertToXMLGregorianCalendar(Date date)  {
        DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        try {
            return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(DateUtils.convertToXMLGregorianCalendar(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting one. It seems the `XMLGregorianCalendar` is not happy with any format that doesn't start with a year. Curious to see what the solution is here.

Comment: Look this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492827/convert-date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar/9493242#9493242](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492827/convert-date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar/9493242#9493242)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `String` to convert from `Date` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`, instead, use:

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar convertToXMLGregorianCalendar(Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
}
```

on the other hand, you can set empty certain fields, the closest to your question is

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xdate = convertToXMLGregorianCalendar(new Date());
System.out.println(xdate.toXMLFormat());

// NOT all combinations are implemented!
xdate.setYear(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
xdate.setHour(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
xdate.setMinute(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
xdate.setSecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
System.out.println(xdate.toXMLFormat());
```

with output

```
2021-08-05T16:51:35.642+02:00
--08-05+02:00
```

see the [getXMLSchemaType](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jaxp/blob/master/src/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java#L1907) implementation.

Comment: Lombok here is unnecessary, and could be confusing for the OP if they aren’t familiar with it.

Comment: `XMLGregorianCalendar` store a date, probably you need touch how it is formatter when the xml is generated (but this is other question than convert `date` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`)